# "VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR" while running "vagrant up" command

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I am getting the below error when i try to run "vagrant up" command.

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'precise32'...
Progress: 30%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagr
ant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command:

```
["import", "C:/Users/username/.vagrant.d/boxes/precise32/0/virtualbox/b
ox.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "precise32_1417450998781_63238", "--vsys", "
0", "--unit", "9", "--disk", "X:\\VirtualBox VMs\\precise32_1417450998781_63238\
\box-disk1.vmdk"]
```

Stderr:

```
0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting C:\Users\username\.vagrant.d\boxes\precise32\0\virtualbox\box.ovf..
```

.
OK.
0%...10%...20%...30%...
Progress state:

```
VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage.exe: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage.exe: error: Could not create the imported medium 'X:\VirtualBox VMs\p
recise32_1417450998781_63238\box-disk1.vmdk'.
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in 'X:\VirtualBox
VMs\precise32_1417450998781_63238/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component A
ppliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage.exe: error: Context: "int __cdecl handleImportAppliance(struct Handle
rArg *)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

I am not using an 'X' drive and I have already set the "VAGRANT_HOME" variable to the home directory in the environment variables, i.e, VAGRANT_HOME and its value C:\Users\username.vagrant.d

I already have the ".vagrant" directory and other dirs inside it.

Can anyone please tell me why I am still getting the above error when i run "vagrant up" command and any solution for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error `VERR_DISK_FULL` seems to tell that your disk is full.

```
VBoxManage.exe: error: VMDK: cannot write allocated data block in 'X:\VirtualBox
VMs\precise32_1417450998781_63238/box-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_DISK_FULL)
```

Try freeing some space on your `C:/` drive. I don't know the minimum but I think you have to have more then 1 gb free.